# Undefined index: google_analytics_json_key symfony 4

Tags: symfony

I have a simple blog developed on Symfony 4, on which I want to add a statistics view of articles. I decided to use Google Analytics.
I add to base.html.twig this code:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-134720857-1"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', 'UA-*********-*');
    </script>
```

And also installed this bundle https://github.com/mediafigaro/google-analytics-api-symfony.
According to the documentation, I have to set the path to my json file. In my case it looks like this:

```
//config/services.yaml
parameters:
    google_analytics_json_key: ../data/analytics/client_secret.json
    google_analytics_view_id: 'yourViewId'

services:

    // ....

    google_analytics_api:
        google_analytics_json_key: "%google_analytics_json_key%"
```

These actions cause an error:

```
In FileLoader.php line 166:

    The configuration key "google_analytics_json_key" is unsupported for 
definition "google_analytics_api" in 
"/var/www/blog/config/services.yaml". Allowed confi  
guration keys are "alias", "parent", "class", "shared", "synthetic", 
"lazy", "public", "abstract", "deprecated", "factory", "file", 
"arguments", "properties"  
 , "configurator", "calls", "tags", "decorates", 
"decoration_inner_name", "decoration_priority", "autowire", 
"autoconfigure", "bind" in /var/www/blog/config/
services.yaml(which is loaded in resource 
"/var/www/blog/config/services.yaml").                                                                               


In YamlFileLoader.php line 813:

 The configuration key "google_analytics_json_key" is unsupported for 
definition "google_analytics_api" in 
"/var/www/blog/config/services.yaml". Allowed configuration keys are 
"alias", "parent", "class", "shared", "synthetic", 
"lazy", "public", "abstract", "deprecated", "factory", "file", 
"arguments", "properties", "configurator", "calls", "tags", 
"decorates", 
"decoration_inner_name", "decoration_priority", "autowire", 
"autoconfigure", "bind".
```

Please help)) If certain pieces of code are needed, I will gladly present them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing services.yml with config.yml.
Check here carefully:

https://github.com/mediafigaro/google-analytics-api-symfony#configuration

```
google_analytics_api:
        google_analytics_json_key: "%google_analytics_json_key%"
```

This part should be in `config.yml`, not `services.yml` `(/app/config/config.yml)`

`"%google_analytics_json_key%"` denotes a parameter you defined under `parameters` key, which can also be in your `config.yml`.

Try pasting this in newly created file `config/packages/google_analytics_api.yaml`

```
google_analytics_api:
    google_analytics_json_key: "../data/analytics/client_secret.json"
```

Comment: I do not have this file (( https://savepice.ru/full/2019/3/1/7d5670be1d89d7b5ba9b012d54a5c888-full.png.html

Comment: Try creating a file called `google_analytics_api.yaml` in `config/packages` folder and paste the contents there.

Comment: and paste what?

Comment: Thank you, the error does not appear anymore, but how can I now use this service to display the number of article views in the template?

Comment: That is out of the scope of this question. I suggest you read the library's documentation and familiarize yourself with it's usage: https://github.com/mediafigaro/google-analytics-api-symfony#example 
If the answer helped you, you can mark it as accepted so that it may help others should they encounter the same issue.